# Yocto version v3.21.0 & QT5

Tags: qt, yocto

I am using yocto v3.21.0 i.e poky-2.4.3.
Trying to add QT5 to the yocto image.

I am following this link:
[Using yocto with qt5](https://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Yocto#Adding_Qt5_in_Yocto_image)

I have added layer for qt5:

```
${TOPDIR}/../meta-qt5
```

I have to include meta-ruby layer, in `bblayers.conf` file :--

```
${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-ruby \
```

But meta-ruby layer is not preset in meta-openembedded.

Please suggest how to get meta-ruby layer ?

Answer (score 1):

QT5 recipes shouldn't be in the `meta-ruby` layer. Take a look at [meta-qt5](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5). Clone that into your source directory and add it to your `bblayer.conf`. You'll have all the QT5 recipes available then.

Comment: I have added qt5 layer... I forget to mention this... I have modified my answer.. but the link which I am following used to tell to add meta-ruby layer..   But meta-ruby layer is not preset in meta-openembedded.. please suggest..

Comment: Did you checkout the correct hash for `meta-openembedded`?
Make sure to execute `git checkout -b tmp dca466c074c9a35bc0133e7e0d65cca0731e2acf` in the meta-openembedded repo